# Command 'Solidity: Compile Contract' resulted in an error (Cannot read properties of undefined(reading 'uri'))

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, solidity, web3js

Good day everyone, I am working on a lottery smart contract. I am currently done with the remix VM tests and proceeded with the unit tests with JavaScript. The test.js file is shown below.

```
const assert = require('assert');
const ganache = require('ganache-cli');
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3(ganache.provider());

const { abi, bytecode } = require('../compile')

let lottery;
let accounts;

beforeEach(async() => {
    accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

    lottery = await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(abi))
    .deploy({ data: evm.bytecode.object })
    .send({ from: accounts[0], gas: 1000000});
});

describe('Lottery Contract', () => {
    it('deploys a contract', () => {
        assert.ok(lottery.options.address);
    });
});
```

The test file for now only checks if the contract deploys, pretty simple. However, I have not been able to proceed from here due to a particular error. Details on that will be shown below. I have checked for syntax and spelling errors but everything seems fine to me. Details on the compile.js and the error are provided below

The compile.js file:

```
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");
const solc = require("solc");

const lotteryPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "contracts", "Lottery.sol");
const source = fs.readFileSync(lotteryPath, "utf8");

const input = {
    language: 'Solidity',
    sources: {
        'Lottery.sol': {
            content: source
        }
    },
    settings: {
        outputSelection: {
            '*': {
                '*': ['*'],
            }
        }
    }
};

// console.log(JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input))).contracts);
module.exports = JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input))).contracts[
     'Lottery.sol'
 ].Lottery;
```

The Error message:

[image: error message]

I made use of imports in the lottery.sol file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am currently debugging the same error as well for a NFT I am publishing... I imported the local directory into my Remix workspace and it compiled just fine... this leads me to believe the issue is a mismatch between compiler versions... not sure. VS Code was irritating me, so I just published through Remix and called it a day.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the quick fix,
Check for the compiler version consistency through out the project (wherever it is used)

1. Select a  solidity compiler version (let's say 0.8.0)
2. Update the same version in truffle-config.js
3. package.json
4. package-lock.json

and compile.
That's it !!

Let me know, incase this doesn't work for you.